# jQuery 360 countdown - Button to add seconds WHILE timer is runnig

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

I need a button that can add seconds while the timer is running. I got the timer from: https://github.com/johnschult/jquery.countdown360. This is the code that I have to put in my HTML.

```
  $("#countdown").countdown360({
         radius      : 120,
         seconds     : 30,
         fontColor   : '#FFFFFF',
         autostart   : false,
         onComplete  : function () { console.log('done') }
       }).start();
```

I tried to make the button myself but no succes.

```
document.getElementById('add').onclick = function(){
        // location.reload();
        $("#countdown").countdown360({seconds += 20}).start()
        }

<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: How about recreating the counter?  Remove the element then add the modified one

Comment: Let's say the timer show 20 secondes I want to have a button that adds a number to the current timer time. So if the buttons does +1 it needs to display 21

Comment: That will depend if the library has an API call that does that. If not, you can remove the element then create a new one with the new start/end time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seconds are stored in `clock.settings.seconds`.

```
var clock = $("#countdown").countdown360({
    radius: 60,
    seconds: 30,
    fontColor: '#FFFFFF',
    autostart: false,
    onComplete: function () {
        console.log('done')
    }
})
clock.start();

$("#countdown").on("click", function() {
    clock.settings.seconds += 20;
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gs3WY/71/) (countdown360.js loaded in firefox but not in chrome)